# Unable to read a path with special characters in FSRef

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

With this code I am trying to get the path in const char *pathPtr from  fsRefAEDesc. It gives the correct name and path if there are no special characters in the name of file which is there in  fsRefAEDesc. Now if path has some special characters /Users/XYZ/.rtf I don't get a correct fsRef from AEGetDescData(). I believe it has some thing to do with Encoding and tried some them but could make it work.

```
FSRef fsRef;
//AEDesc fsRefAEDesc; //comes from some where. 

status = AEGetDescData( &fsRefAEDesc, (void*)(&fsRef), sizeof(FSRef));
//OSErr result = FSMakeFSRefUnicode(&fsRef, 1024, (UniCharPtr)(&fsRef),   kTextEncodingUnknown, &fileRef);
AEDisposeDesc( &fsRefAEDesc );

 CFURLRef* gotURLRef = CFURLCreateFromFSRef(NULL, &fsRef);
 CFStringRef macPath = CFURLCopyFileSystemPath(gotURLRef,  kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle);

 const char *pathPtr = CFStringGetCStringPtr(macPath, CFStringGetSystemEncoding());
```

Is there is any way to read such paths?

Answer (score 1):

At what point in your code does the problem occur?  For instance, if you insert `CFShow(macPath)`, do you see the right path in the debug log?  If so, then you are not passing the right encoding to `CFStringGetCStringPtr`.  Use UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks JWWalker, I don't see the right path when I tried this for macPath.Also tried this for gotURLRef but I got the same on my console 
i.e. "/Users/Manish/Desktop/\u27a4\u00a9\u261a.png". I believe the FSRef that I am getting from AEGetDescData(&fsRefAEDesc, (void*)(&fsRef), sizeof(FSRef)) is not in Unicode. Is there is any way where we can get a correct FSRef. Apart from FSMakeFSRefUnicode()? I don't any other way to convert it into unicode, because it is not working for me. Let me know if there is any way to do so.

Thanks,
M

Comment: It might be that the URL contains the right characters, but the Unicode escapes are being added for display in the log.

An FSRef is a file reference, not a file name.  The FSRef is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Also tried this for gotURLRef but I
>   got the same on my console i.e.
>   "/Users/Manish/Desktop/\u27a4\u00a9\u261a.png"

The Unicode escape sequence is what you get when going through CFURL calls. URL has very [limited character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding) range.

You can try [`FSRefMakePath`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSRefMakePath). It will get you UTF8 encoded path from a FSRef.